# Tricky Rectangle Problem

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

[image]

How many rectangles are there which do not include any yellow squares?

Comment: @hippalectryon nothing so far. I don't know how to start

Comment: Well, you could at least start by counting them by hand ...

Comment: @Hippalectryon  Counting by hand is not realistic since there are $\binom{7}{2}$ ways of selecting the horizontal sides and $\binom{7}{2}$ of selecting the vertical sides if we ignore the requirement that no yellow squares are selected.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I agree.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I was just trying to show that 'I haven't tried anything so far because I don't know how to start' showed a lack of effort.

Comment: @Hippalectryon How's my solution?

Comment: @YagnaPatel Great :-)

Comment: Does anyone else not see an illustration?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: No counting by hand **is realistic**, because it forces one to take short-cuts when counting! Then the shortcuts become an answer!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a more combinatorial/algebraic approach:

Let the Horizontal lines from bottom to top be $h_{0}, h_{1}, ..., h_{6}$ and Vertical lines from left to right be $v_{0}, v_{1}, ..., v_{6}$

Total Rectangles $= {7 \choose 2} \times {7 \choose 2}  = 441$

Rectangles that contain bottom left yellow square is all rectangles that can be formed by choosing one horizontal line from $\{h_{0}, h_{1}\}$, another horizontal line from $\{h_{2}, ..., h_{6}\}$ and one vertical line from $\{v_{0}, v_{1}\}$, another vertical line from $\{v_{2}, ..., v_{6}\}$.

Total number of rectangles that contain bottom left yellow square $=$ $\left({2 \choose 1}  \times {5 \choose 1} \right) \times \left({2 \choose 1}  \times {5 \choose 1}\right)  = 100$

Similarly, total number of rectangles that contain top right yellow square $=$ $\left({2 \choose 1}  \times {5 \choose 1} \right) \times \left({2 \choose 1}  \times {5 \choose 1}\right)  = 100$

Total number of rectangles that contain both the yellow squares are all the rectangles that can be formed by choosing one horizontal line from $\{h_{0}, h_{1}\}$, another horizontal line from $\{h_{5}, h_{6}\}$ and one vertical line from $\{v_{0}, v_{1}\}$, another vertical line from $\{v_{5}, v_{6}\}$.

Total number of rectangles that contain both the yellow squares $=$ $\left({2 \choose 1}  \times {2 \choose 1} \right) \times \left({2 \choose 1}  \times {2 \choose 1}\right)  = 16$

From principle of inclusion-exclusion:
Rectangles without any yellow squares $=$ $441 - (100+100-16) = 257$

Comment: Wow, this is a quite solid proof in a very short time, bravo.

Comment: It came in handy then, congrats.

Comment: May I ask why the total rectangles is $^7C_2 \times ^7C_2$?

Comment: @bnosnehpets  A rectangle is determined by its sides.  There are seven vertical lines, from which we must choose two to form the vertical sides.  Similarly, there are seven horizontal lines, from which we must choose two to form the horizontal sides.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig right, thanks that makes sense

Comment: @mvw Basically $7C_2$ is the same as ${7 \choose 2}$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Great explanation!

Comment: @YagnaPatel  I could say the same about your solution to this problem.  Nice job.

Comment: This is a very concise solution.

Comment: Any chance that the question, as stated, could be read to exclude counting "square" rectangles?

Comment: How come  that my comment suggesting this approach has been deleted from the comments to the question?

Answer (score 12):

[image: rectangle counter]

What I did is, in each square, count the number of rectangles that could be drawn having the same upper left corner as that square, which also do not include the shaded squares I also got 257. I hope someone will check my work. I have a bit of a dyslexia - type problem and it's really hard for me to do things like this without messing up.

Comment: My row sums are: $64 + 43 + 64 + 43 + 22 + 21 = 257$

Comment: @Steven Gregory: i like this proof. Very elegant.

Comment: @DavidQuinn: Thanks. I like that the sums are symmetrical about the diagonal.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an illustration to Yagna Patel's solution:

[image: rectangles]

Each possible rectangle is described by the choice of two horizontal and two vertical lines. This helps to emphasize the choice aspect.
See e.g. the lower yellow rectangle $(h_1, h_2, v_1, v_2)$.

The lines can also be viewed as coordinate lines and we could say that rectangle has a lower left point $(1,1)$ and a higher right point $(2,2)$.

Comment: Nice, this is a great visual.